# Background subtraction for Luminex data

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large data table similar to this:

```
library(data.table)

mydata <- fread(
  "PID,Stim,Analyte1,Analyte2,Analyte3
  123, SA, 5678, 6578, 4893
  123, UNS, 56, 45, 67
  123, LPS, 4467, 4356, 8573
  234, SA, 6657, 4455, 6589
  234, UNS, 89, 35, 67
  234, LPS, 4578, 7856, 9845
  567, SA, 7888, 5637, 6784
  567, UNS, 85, 67, 87
  567, LPS, 5673, 4834, 4893
")
```

I would like to perform background subtraction for each PID (patient ID), based on the Stim column. I would like to subtract the unstim from each stim condition (SA and LPS) per patient ID for each analyte. I'm fairly new to r, thus no example of what I've tried before.

What would be the best way to perform background subtraction when dealing with a large data table?

Answer (score 1):

You could join subsets of the `data.table`:

```
 mydata[Stim=='UNS'][mydata[Stim!='UNS'],on=.(PID)]

     PID   Stim Analyte1 Analyte2 Analyte3 i.Stim i.Analyte1 i.Analyte2 i.Analyte3
   <int> <char>    <int>    <int>    <int> <char>      <int>      <int>      <int>
1:   123    UNS       56       45       67     SA       5678       6578       4893
2:   123    UNS       56       45       67    LPS       4467       4356       8573
3:   234    UNS       89       35       67     SA       6657       4455       6589
4:   234    UNS       89       35       67    LPS       4578       7856       9845
5:   567    UNS       85       67       87     SA       7888       5637       6784
6:   567    UNS       85       67       87    LPS       5673       4834       4893
```

Allowing you to substract analytes:

```
mydata[Stim=='UNS'][mydata[Stim!='UNS'],.(PID, Stim = i.Stim, 
                                          Sub1 = i.Analyte1 - Analyte1,
                                          Sub2 = i.Analyte2 - Analyte2,
                                          Sub3 = i.Analyte3 - Analyte3),
                    on=.(PID)]

     PID   Stim  Sub1  Sub2  Sub3
   <int> <char> <int> <int> <int>
1:   123     SA  5622  6533  4826
2:   123    LPS  4411  4311  8506
3:   234     SA  6568  4420  6522
4:   234    LPS  4489  7821  9778
5:   567     SA  7803  5570  6697
6:   567    LPS  5588  4767  4806
```

To generalize over more analytes, you could use expression evaluation :

```
nbAnalytes <- 3
expr<- paste("list(PID, Stim = i.Stim,",paste(sapply(1:nbAnalytes,function(i) paste0("Sub", i, "= i.Analyte",i," - Analyte",i)),collapse=','),")")
expr
# [1] "list(PID, Stim = i.Stim, Sub1= i.Analyte1 - Analyte1,Sub2= i.Analyte2 - Analyte2,Sub3= i.Analyte3 - Analyte3 )"


dt[,eval(rlang::parse_expr(expr))]

     PID   Stim  Sub1  Sub2  Sub3
   <int> <char> <int> <int> <int>
1:   123     SA  5622  6533  4826
2:   123    LPS  4411  4311  8506
3:   234     SA  6568  4420  6522
4:   234    LPS  4489  7821  9778
5:   567     SA  7803  5570  6697
6:   567    LPS  5588  4767  4806
```

Comment: thanks, this is very useful. My actual data.table has a large number of analytes(variables). Also, I often have data that requires background subtraction with a lot of variables and observations. I was hoping that there could be a quicker way to go about this. I've been stuck trying to create a for loop for this problem.

Comment: @M.M., this is a good approach, and given the structure/complexity of data you've provided, I don't know that you'll get better while maintaining generality and readability. However, if you can better inform what is not ideal about this and what your true goals are (more general? subtract more than just `UNS` from all others? expect output?)

Comment: @r2evans I was hoping to loop over the columns (analytes) of the data.table and subtract UNS from the Stim conditions (LPS, SA etc.) per PID.  So that I wouldn't manually have to specify the analytes in the code which would take a long time (because I usually have a lot of analytes to work with) and I could possibly introduce errors.

Comment: Nothing in Waldi's answer relies on the names or number of non-`UNS` in `Stim`. If you have 3 or 30 other analytes, I suspect that this answer will work as-is. Verify in the code above that Waldi's code never references `SA` or `LPS`. I think that's as generalized as you can get. Have you tried it with your real data? If it isn't performing correctly, perhaps you may need to update your question to indicate what about this solution doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Oh, I think I see, I'm mixing terms. You have 2 or more `Stim`s, and you ave more than 3 `Analyte`s. I see, one more level of indirection is what you're looking for.

Comment: @r2evans Yes, I usually have about 5 different Stim conditions (UNS, LPS, SA, CA, MT) and 48 plus analytes. I was hoping to not have to manually specify the analytes in the code.

Comment: See my edit with expression evaluation